# How do services like Dropbox implement delta encoding if their files are stored in the cloud?

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, rsync, dropbox

Dropbox claims that during syncing only the portion of files that changes are transmitted back to main server, which is obviously a great functionality, but how do they perform changes to files stored in Amazon S3 cloud? So for example, lets say a 30 page document on user's desktop contains changes to only page 4. Dropbox now syncs the blocks representing the changes and what happens on the backend if they files that they store are in the cloud? Does that mean they have to download the 30 page document stored in S3 to their server, then perform replacement of blocks representing page 4, and then uploading back to the cloud? I doubt this would be the case because that would be somewhat inefficient. The other option I could think of is if Amazon S3 provides update of file stored in the cloud based on byte ranges, so for example, make a PUT request to file X from bytes 100-200 which will replace all the bytes from 100 to 200 with value of PUT request. So I was curious how companies that use other cloud services such as Amazon, implement this type of syncing.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

As S3 and similar storages don't offer filesystem capabilities, anything that pretends to store files and directories needs to emulate a file system. And when doing this files are often split to pages of certain size, where each page is stored in a separate file in the storage. This way the changed block requires uploading only one page (for example) and not the whole file. I should note, that with files like office documents this approach can be faulty if file size is changed - for example, if you insert a page at the beginning or delete a page, then the whole file will be changed and the complete file would need to be re-uploaded. We didn't analyze how Dropbox in particular does his job, and I just described the common scenario. There exist also different "patch algorithms", where a patch can be created locally (if Dropbox has an older local copy in the cache) and then applied to one or more blocks on the server.

Answer (score 0):

There are several synchronizing tools which transfer deltas over the wire like rsync, rdiff, rdiff-backup, etc. For bi-directional synchronising with S3 there are paid services like [s3rsync](http://www.s3rsync.com/#) for example. For pure client-side synchronising, tools like [zsync](http://zsync.moria.org.uk/) can be considered (which is what many people employ to roll-out app updates).

An alternative approach would be to tar-ball a directory, generate a delta file (using rdiff or xdelta3), and upload the delta file by using a timestamp as part of the key. In order to sync, all you need to do is to perform these 2 checks client-side:

1. You have all the delta files from S3. If not pull them and apply them to generate the latest backup state.
2. Your last backup state corresponds to your current directory. If not generate a new delta file and push to S3.

The concerning factor here would be the at least 100% additional space utilization, client-side. But this approach will help you revert changes if needed.